# How this save method on mongoose works without saying which database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

So first, I have a workspace folder called "Projects"

In this folder, I have 2 folders:

***Models:***

1) Something-model =>

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Something-Schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  weight: Number,
  length: Number
});
const Something-model = mongoose.model(
  "SomeModel",
  Something-Schema
);

module.exports = Something-model;
```

Job: A model for a record.

***Database***:

1) Connection.js =>

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost/Database",
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);
mongoose.connection
  .once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connection has been made!");
  })
  .on("error", err => {
    console.log("Connection hasn't been made. Got this: " + err);
  });
```

**Job**: It connects to the database.

2) Saving-test.js =>

```
let assert = require("assert");
let someModel = require("../Models/StevenChars");
// Data Saving Test

describe("Data-Saving", function() {
  it("Saving a data to database", function() {
    let Record-One = new someModel({
      name: "Jack",
      weight: 55,
      height: 150
    });
    Record-One.save().then(function() {
      assert(Record-One.isNew === false);
    });
  });
});
```

**Job**: To save a record to the database.

Now the problem is that how save() is supposed to save anything if it doesn't know the location of the database it's going to save to(Which is in Connection.js btw)?

I did it in mocha and it says that the test has passed but I'm still confused how this works. I only followed steps of Net Ninja tutorial but he didn't explain how save() actually works.

So how this works? Excuse me guys if this is a stupid question, I'm a very beginner to servers and databases and I searched about how save works and I didn't get the answer I did. I would really be thankful if someone tried to explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

From what it seems you are trying to do the goal is to create a mocha unit test which would write to mongodb via mongoose as a provider.

Ok so that is the task at hand. To do that you need to be familiar with few things:

1. [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and how tests are written. Why do you need ["before" and "after"](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) and their main purpose.
2. [Mongoose Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) and how they work in terms of [CRUD](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)
3. [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/) so you can actually connect and see if you got the expected results after/during your tests

With that being said here is an example of such a test:

```
describe('Database Tests', function() {
  //Before starting the test, create a  database connection
  //Once a connection is established invoke done()
  before(function (done) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDatabase');
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
    db.once('open', function() {
      console.log('We are connected to test database!');
      done();
    });
  });
  describe('Test Database', function() {
    //Save object with 'name' value of 'Mike"
    it('New name saved to test database', function(done) {
      var testName = Name({
        name: 'Mike'
      });

      testName.save(done);
    });    
  });
  //After all tests are finished drop database and close connection
  after(function(done){
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(){
      mongoose.connection.close(done);
    });
  });
});
```

You can see more of this [example here](https://medium.com/nongaap/beginners-guide-to-writing-mongodb-mongoose-unit-tests-using-mocha-chai-ab5bdf3d3b1d) or just search for `mocha mongoose testing`.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. It's not about save method, I just had to run the connection together with all the files by using Mocha

That's all. The post can be closed and solved now.